# SQL Database Address

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm writing an application in `C#` and I am using a `SQL` database too keep some information. I have defined the `database` address to make a connection like this:

```
  @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\pouya\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\DataBaseDLL\DataBaseDLL\Database.mdf
```

In this case when I run the application on another computer it causes an error because the address is incorrect.

Is there any way that I can fix this error?  For example, making the application look for it in the same folder like ..`\\database.mdf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a relative path to your *.mdf file.

The following connectionString looks for the mdf file within your App_Data folder. Put this connectionString into your web.config:

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="YourConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  
</connectionStrings>
```

The `|DataDirectory|` is doing the trick...

Answer (score 0):

So you are running the application on another computer and the connection string is not able to find the location of the database because it does not match the path? Is that correct?

In that case you could build the connection string yourself.

For example:

```
    public class Example
    {

       string dirInfo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
       string connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + dirInfo + "\documents\visual studio       2010\Projects\DataBaseDLL\DataBaseDLL\Database.mdf"

    }
```

granted, there are much better ways of doing this.